# Change buttons on a vbYesNo input box to custom options

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project in which I am trying to minimize the amount of user input needed. To do this I have added in some input boxes which I use as variables within my VBA code. What I would like to do is change these from input boxes that require typing to a Yes/No style including the options I need.

For example, one of the input boxes is used to decide if figures are output as either a percentage or count. The code I use for this is below.

```
'Output option:
OutputType = InputBox("How would you like your table output? Your options are 'Percentage' or 'Count')")

If OutputType = "" Then
    MsgBox "You did not enter a valid answer. This macro will now stop and you should run it again with a valid answer!"
    Exit Sub

ElseIf UCase(OutputType) <> "PERCENTAGE" Then
    If UCase(OutputType) <> "COUNT" Then
        MsgBox "You did not enter a valid answer. This macro will now stop and you should run it again with a valid answer!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End If

If UCase(OutputType) = "PERCENTAGE" Then
Expression = InputBox("Would you like your percentages expressed as a fraction of the row total ('Row Total'), Column Total ('Column Total') or the total ('Total')?")
End If

If UCase(OutputType) = "COUNT" Then
    Rounded = InputBox("Would you like to round the values? ('Yes'/'No')")
        If UCase(Rounded) = "YES" Then
            Rounding = InputBox("Enter the nearest multiple you'd like your figures rounded to!")
        End If
End If
```

Where I use an input box I would prefer the user have the choice to click either a 'Percentage' button or  a 'Count' button. This will help avoid spelling errors as well as people not knowing what all the options are for each particular box.
I would also like to extend this to more than two choices up until say 5 different options.

UPDATE: I have created the userform using a `ComboBox`.
The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

'SeeInfo - Display Project Information.
Me.ComboBox1.Clear

Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Yes"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "No"

'OutputType - How the numbers are displayed.
Me.ComboBox2.Clear

Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Percentage"
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Count"

'Expression - Used if OutputType is Percentage.
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "Row Total"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "Column Total"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "Grand Total"

'Rounded - Used if OutputType is Count and is asking if you would like to round the values.
Me.ComboBox4.Clear

Me.ComboBox4.AddItem "Yes"
Me.ComboBox4.AddItem "No"

'Rounding - The nearest integer to round to.
Me.ComboBox5.Clear

Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "1"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "2"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "3"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "4"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "5"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "6"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "7"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "8"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "9"
Me.ComboBox5.AddItem "10"

'ChartType - How the HTML code will display the graphs.
Me.ComboBox6.Clear

Me.ComboBox6.AddItem "Bar"
Me.ComboBox6.AddItem "Line"
Me.ComboBox6.AddItem "Column"
Me.ComboBox6.AddItem "Spline"
Me.ComboBox6.AddItem "Pie"

End Sub
```

From here i need to take each input from each `ComboBox` and use them for their respective variables in the Module my project is in.
Is there a way to do this like, for example, `SeeInfo=ComboBox1.Value` within the module where the `SeeInfo` variable is being used?

**SOLVED**
I created individual functions for each `ComboBox` and their desired input. An example can be found below where i would like to know how the figures are to be displayed. This is done in the same module and called in the main `Sub`.

```
Sub Example()
'OutputType_ComboBox extracts the entry of the ComboBox
OutputType = OutputType_ComboBox
If OutputType = "Percentage" then 
Activesheet.Cells(1,1) = (Figure/PercentFigure)*100
End Sub

Function OutputType_ComboBox() As String
'Create the User Form as component first
Dim myFormComponent As VBIDE.VBcomponent
Set myFormComponent = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

' Get reference to user form from the UserForms collection then
Dim cb1 As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim myForm As Variant
Dim Variable As String

Set myForm = VBA.UserForms.Add(myFormComponent.Name)

With myForm
    .Width = 400
    .Height = 300
End With


'OutputType
Set cb1 = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With cb1
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 100
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 200
    .AddItem "Percentage"
    .AddItem "Count"
    .Value = "How would you like your figures displayed?"
 End With
    myForm.Show
    MsgBox "Output Type Response: " & cb1.Value

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove myFormComponent
    OutputType_ComboBox = cb1.Value

End Function
```

Apologies for the sloppy code in the last section here as the project is fairly cumbersome and so this is a trivial example to get the point across.
Thank you for the help on this.

Comment: I would suggest using radio buttons / check boxes, maybe in combination with frames.

Comment: You cannot change the regular MsgBox buttons. Create a custom form and show as dialog (modal).

Comment: As @KostasK. said, you cannot achieve what you are asking with Inputbox/MsgBox. You will need to develop your own custom user form(s). If you haven't built one before, then this is your opportunity to learn how to do it: Nothing helps one learn more than a project. All the best

Comment: @prextor Do you mean in a custom user form?

Comment: You can formulate your text in something like ".....In order to choose ""Percentage"" please press ""Yes""." And use a standard Yes/No MsgBox.

Comment: Sounds like you could use `ComboBox` or a `ListBox` in a form